# How to make sql sequelize query with nested relations where clause

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

Im currently working on a budget tracking web app that has the corresponding database setup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njXnx.png)

So basically i have multiple transactions reladed to a single account, as well as multiple accounts related to a single user

i want to come up with a sequelize query that allows me to view every transaction done by any account corresponding to a single user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have associations look like this:

```js
// these definitions are simplified for demonstration purposes
User.hasMany(Account);
Account.hasMany(Transaction);
Account.belongsTo(User);
Transaction.belongsTo(Account);
```

We can get all user's transactions like this:

```js
const transactions = await Transaction.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: Account,
    required: true,
    include: [{
     model: User,
     required: true,
     where: {
       id: userId // here is the condition on a certain user id
     }
    }]
  }]
})
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I've been thinking of the include as just something that's just useful for bringing related key value pairs but i realize that is necesary for any mildly complex sql join operation